# Unexpected EOF when using '-c' flag on sudo

Tags: linux, terminal

I have been trying to pick up sudo on my own and have been stuck on this side issue for days.

When running the command below, I am able to produce the correct altered information with the two attributes (D,44.... and E,44....) in file1.txt as separate lines before 'TESTINFORMATION'.

```
sed '/TESTINFORMATION/i\attribute="D,44444,44444" \nattribute="E,44444,44444"' file.txt >> file1.txt
```

However if I try and execute the command as passed in to the 'c' parameter for sudo, I keep getting an unexpected EOF:

```
sudo -S su - root -c 'sed \'/TESTINFORMATION/i\attribute="D,44444,44444" \nattribute="E,44444,44444"\' file.txt >> file1.txt'
```

I have looked at the paired apostrophes and escaped characters, but I still haven't seen my error.

What is best practice for troubleshooting EOFs?

**Solution: I tried both DopeGhoti's solution and steeldriver's solution and they both worked. One example of a working solution was:**

```
sudo -S su - root -c '\''sed \'/TESTINFORMATION/i\attribute="D,44444,44444" \nattribute="E,44444,44444"\'\'' file.txt >> file1.txt'
```

Thank you all for your time :)

Comment: It may work if you replace `'` with `'\''` i.e. close the outer strong quote and re-open it, with a literal `'` in between - but it would be better IMHO to use a more transparent solution such as a here-document to avoid the nesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a 'strong quoted' string which you are trying to embed in 'strong quotes'.  This will not work.  The ugly answer is to escape the internal quotes; the probably-better-and-easier-to-manage answer is to take your lexically complex `sed` command, put it into a script, and execute the script itself with `sudo`, e. g. `sudo /path/to/sed_script.sh`.

Using `sudo` to execute `su -S su - root -c 'somecommand'` is a *very* roundabout way to just run `sudo somecommand`.

Comment: I recognize it is a very roundabout way, but because I'm learning in the context of an automation suite w/ permissions set on file.txt, I am unfortunately unable to create a script or run without sudoing root (???). 

So for the suggested 'ugly answer', do you mean replacing all double quotes with \"?

Comment: Yes.  The short version is that inside a quoted string, you need to escape the quote character containing the string, otherwise it will terminate.  For instance `echo "He said, \"hello\" to me."` or `echo 'He told me last week, "stop pressing the button labeled \'do not press\'."'`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think I understand it now. Just to round out my knowledge, I also tried @steeldriver's solution and they both worked. :) I also learned that 'sed' won't output if the output file name already exists. Thank you all so much for your time!